# ns3 simulation - Running fail

Tags: networking, ns-3

I`m very new in NS3 simulation.
I have one question regarding run my code.
I did ./waf --run but I got this error:

> aidas-MacBook-Pro:ns-3.26 Aida$ ./waf --run scratch/scenario2 Waf:
>   Entering directory
>   `/Users/Aida/Documents/ns3/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/build' Waf:
>   Leaving directory`
>   /Users/Aida/Documents/ns3/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/build' Build
>   commands will be stored in build/compile_commands.json 'build'
>   finished successfully (2.680s) msg="Could not open trace file
>   scratch/mobility3.tcl for reading, aborting here  ",
>   file=../src/mobility/helper/ns2-mobility-helper.cc, line=189
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating Command
>   ['/Users/Aida/Documents/ns3/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/build/scratch/scenario2']
>   terminated with signal SIGIOT. Run it under a debugger to get more
>   information (./waf --run  --command-template="gdb --args %s
>   ").

Can anyone help me for solve this issue?

Comment: it well be more easy if you put your scenario 2 file also

Comment: somehow I can solved my problem. I miss tcl file! and I found it on internet!